# Regex Issue: Difference between 'seconds?' and 'second(?:s)?'

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I am trying to understand and practicing the following. I guess `(?:s)?` and `s?` providing the same result

```
  let str = "second"; 
  let res = str.match(/second(?:s)?/g);
  console.log(res); //["second"]

  let res = str.match(/seconds?/g);
  console.log(res); //["second"]
```

Is there any difference between them?
Thanks

Comment: There is no difference, because `?` associates with only the `s` even without the non-capturing group. Also, since the group is non-capturing, it won't do anything extra (such as capturing) other than grouping.

Comment: Actually [one uses 10 steps](https://regex101.com/r/N0XF8g/1), the other [uses 8 steps](https://regex101.com/r/HvQk2g/1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example, there's no real difference because the regex with `?` doesn't use a capturing group either. If you placed the `s` inside a capturing group, added the `s` to the input string, and removed the global flag from the regex, then you'd see a difference:

```js
let str = "seconds";
let res = str.match(/second(s)?/g);
console.log(res);
```

But no, the non-capturing group `(?:)` has no real difference to the optional statement `?` when used in this context.

Answer (score 1):

Non-capturing group `(?:...)` and capturing group `(...)` do not have any effect if their content is only 1 character and for capturing group if you do not use back reference to it.

You usually use groups when you want to extend the effect of quantifiers (`?`, `{N}`, `{N,M}`, `+`, `*`) to not only the preceding character but to several ones (the group).

**Examples:**

```
secon(ds)?
secon(?:ds)?
```

will both match

```
secon
```

and

```
seconds
```

Because `?` will affect both `d` and `s`, in this case it will give a different result than `seconds?`.

---

Another use of groups is when you want to use **alternatives** in the group:

```
time in (?:seconds?|hours?|minutes?) is a good example
```

and

```
time in second is a good example
time in seconds is a good example
time in hours is a good example
time in hour is a good example
time in minute is a good example
time in minutes is a good example
```

where you put alternatives between second(s), hour(s) and minute(s) within the group

---

Last but not least **backreferences**:

Find the words for which the first char is the same as the last one

```
^(\w)\w*\1$
```

and input:

```
aba
aaabbba
test
apple
car
```

where the first three lines will match. demo: https://regex101.com/r/nrDCvn/1